# Why is DateTime.Now showing as short date format in VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

I have 2 applications, in both at the time of user login I store a record in a table called `Logs` to track what time users logged in. In the first application `DateTime.Now` saves as:

`2017-11-24 16:20:17.417`

In my second application DateTime.Now saves as:

`2017-11-24`

Here is the actual save

```
var log = new UserLog
{
    user = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == customer),
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now
};    
_cxt.Logs.Add(log);
_cxt.SaveChanges();
```

The save looks the same in both applications, the only difference is that the long one was created in VS2013 while the shorter one was created in VS2015.

Comment: What is the type of the column in SQL?

Comment: what is the environment of that machine setup as in regards to Culture and the datetime format.. when you debug what is the actual value of CreateDate.?

Comment: How are you checking the value?

Comment: Date in both cases

Comment: Is this a SQL Server table? If it is, then the column type can't be `date`, as that would store the date without time in both cases. We need to know the type of the actual column in `Logs` in the database.

Comment: `In my second application DateTime.Now saves as` Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for that second application's database. Also have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql

Comment: One was Date and one was DateTime in SQL. I apologize for the delay in response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check these piece of codes:

1. In SQL table UserLog field **CreateDate** type certainly is **DateTime** and not **Date**.
2. In UserLog class not use **DataAnnotations** like this [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
3. Check the **Calendar** or **DateTime** helper class in your project.
4. Before store CreateDate **value** in database check it with a breakpoint.

Comment: One was Date and one was DateTime in SQL. I apologize for the delay in response.